# Grouped product getFinalPrice behavior in Magento

Tags: magento

How can I change getFinalPrice behavior for grouped product in Magento? I want to get final price for grouped product which not using children products with specific attribute value in result calculation

Answer (score 1):

If you call the `getFinalPrice()` method on a grouped product's price model (`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped_Price`) without supplying a quantity, `getFinalPrice()` will return the previously calculated final price for the product. i.e.

```
return $product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
```

The `getCalculatedFinalPrice()` method is essentially just a wrapper around the magic getter....

```
return $this->_getData('calculated_final_price');
```

The corresponding `setCalculatedFinalPrice` call is found in the product collection class (`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`), in the `_addFinalPrice()` method.

When you dig into the implementation of the method, you'll find it defers to the `calculatePrice()` method in the product's own price model.  Because `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped_Price` doesn't provide an implementation for this method, the version from the parent `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` is used.  Essentially this encapsulates all of the logic for dealing with base price/spacial price, price rules, etc.

Which leads to the conclusion that without any quantity, options, etc specified, calling `getFinalPrice()` on a grouped product will return the price of the grouped product itself.

Comment: in the case where no quantities or options are passed to the getFinalPrice(), does it take account of Catalog Price or Shopping Cart rules?

Comment: It looks like it does.  I haven't confirmed by trying it for real, but there appears to be support for special prices, tier prices and catalog rules.  Shopping cart rules probably aren't applicable when you're just trying to get he price for a grouped product without any options selected.