# Which Attribute Should I Select to getFinalPrice

Tags: magento

I have the following code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();


foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->load();
    $price = $product->getFinalPrice();
    //do something with $price
}
```

Obviously with the `$product->load()` performance is horrible but when I remove that `$price` is zero and so I am looking for something like `addAttributeToSelect` to make it so I do not need to load each product.  I have tried the price attribute but that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price.html

```
Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($product->setStoreId('STORE_ID')->setCustomerGroupId('CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID'),$product->getPrice())
```

or

```
Mage::getModel(‘catalogrule/rule’)->calcProductPriceRule($product,$product->getPrice())
```

You may also want to take a look here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/176883/

[Grouped product getFinalPrice behavior in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256442/grouped-product-getfinalprice-behavior-in-magento)

Comment: Thanks, sadly neither work.  They both use $product->getPrice() which requires $product to be loaded.